Не работает bs.find
Код:
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("your_token") # сюда вставляете ваш токен бота
url = "https://dtf.ru/kek/entries/new"
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.90 Safari/537.36"
}

while True: # Бесконечный цикл
    def meme(): # Обьявляем функцию
        r = requests.get(url, headers=header).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        bs = soup.find('div', class_='content-image')
        bs2 = bs.find('div', class_='andropov_image')
        list = open("list.txt", "w+")
        link = (bs2['data-image-src']) # Сам парсер мемов
        if link not in list:
            with open("list.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write(link)
                bot.send_photo(5882572736, link) # Отправляем сообщение
                print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Отправил") # лог в консоль
        else:
            print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Новых мемов пока нет") # лог в консоль
    meme() # вызываем функцию
    time.sleep(10) # перерыв между проверкой на новые мемы(время в секундах)

Вывод в терминале:
PS D:\> & d:/C-IT-1/OzerovMikhail/tkanyesite/site/venv/Scripts/python.exe "c:/Users/Student/import tigfgfgme.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Student\import tigfgfgme.py", line 28, in <module>
    meme() # вызываем функцию
    ^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Student\import tigfgfgme.py", line 18, in meme    
    bs2 = bs.find('div', class_='andropov_image')
          ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
PS D:\> 


Так, а в чём проблема? В ошибке явно указано "Объект 'NoneType' не имеет атрибута 'find'". И вам явно показывают на переменную bs, значит эта строка: soup.find('div', class_='content-image') не нашла нужный вам объект и вернула None. Смотрите что возвращает requests и корректируйте ваш код.
